# Securing an API with HTTP AUTH and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So far I have:

```
authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest do |username,password|

end
```

but I dont know how to pass these values to devise to return / signin a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following works for me.

Hope it helps someone else::::

```
before_filter :check_auth


  def check_auth
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username,password|
      resource = User.find_by_email(username)
      if resource.valid_password?(password)
        sign_in :user, resource
      end
    end
  end
```